# Scraping Amazon prices by country

Tags: go, web-scraping

Currently my scraper does his job by zip code, how can I change it to scrape by Country?

Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/4Q6m8RPR

I need to save the "country" in the cookies, at the moment I'm only saving the "zip code", it has two functions that access the website and then "capture" the cookies.

```golang
func ChangeZipCode(purl string, proxies []dal.Proxy, zipCode string) {
    cookieContainer = make(map[string]string)
    u, err := url.Parse(purl)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println(err)
    } else {
        logger.Println(u)
    }
    formData := "locationType=LOCATION_INPUT&zipCode=" + zipCode + "&storeContext=generic&deviceType=web&pageType=Gateway&actionSource=glow&almBrandId=undefined"
    domainFix := "com"
    searchTxt := "\"Tu dirección de envío actual es:\""
    if strings.Contains(purl, "www.amazon.es") {
        domainFix = "es"
        searchTxt = "\"Tu dirección de envío actual es:\""
    } else if strings.Contains(purl, "www.amazon.de") {
        domainFix = "de"
        searchTxt = "\"Sie kaufen gerade ein für:\""
    } else if strings.Contains(purl, "www.amazon.fr") {
        domainFix = "fr"
        searchTxt = "\"Votre lieu de livraison est désormais:\""
    } else if strings.Contains(purl, "www.amazon.co.uk") {
        domainFix = "co.uk"
        searchTxt = "\"You're now shopping for delivery to:\""
    } else if strings.Contains(purl, "www.amazon.it") {
        domainFix = "it"
        searchTxt = "\"L'indirizzo di consegna selezionato è:\""
    } else {
        domainFix = "com"
        searchTxt = "\"You're now shopping for delivery to:\""
    }
 
    homePage := ""
    homePage, err = getRequest("https://www.amazon."+domainFix, proxies)
 
    //uidCookie := strings.TrimLeft(strings.TrimRight(homePage, "\" })</script>"), "/ah/ajax/counter?ctr=desktop_ajax_atf")
    uidCookie := GetStringInBetweenTwoString(homePage, "/ah/ajax/counter?ctr=desktop_ajax_atf", "\" })</script>")
 
    uidCookieUrl := "https://www.amazon." + domainFix + "/ah/ajax/counter?ctr=desktop_ajax_atf" + uidCookie
    postRequest(uidCookieUrl, proxies, "")
    tokenPage := ""
    tokenPage, err = getRequest("https://www.amazon."+domainFix+"/gp/glow/get-address-selections.html?deviceType=desktop&pageType=Gateway&storeContext=NoStoreName", proxies)
    //crosToken := strings.TrimLeft(strings.TrimRight(tokenPage, "\", IDs:{\"ADDRESS_LIST\":\"GLUXAddressList\""), "\"You're now shopping for delivery to:\", CSRF_TOKEN : \"")
    crosToken := GetStringInBetweenTwoString(tokenPage, searchTxt+", CSRF_TOKEN : \"", "\", IDs:{\"ADDRESS_LIST\":\"GLUXAddressList\"")
    changeZipCodePostRequest("https://www.amazon."+domainFix+"/gp/delivery/ajax/address-change.html", proxies, formData, crosToken)
    postRequest("https://www.amazon."+domainFix+"/gp/glow/get-location-label.html", proxies, "storeContext=hpc&pageType=Landing")
 
}
```

```golang
func changeZipCodePostRequest(surl string, proxies []dal.Proxy, formData string, token string) (string, error, bool) {
    logger.Println("processing", surl)
    var client fasthttp.Client
    if len(proxies) > 0 {
        px := getRandomProxy(proxies)
        client = fasthttp.Client{
            Dial: proxy.FastHTTPProxyDialer(px),
        }

        logger.Println("with proxy", px)
    }

    defer client.CloseIdleConnections()

    req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
    resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)
    // Acquire cookie jar
    u, errUrl := url.Parse(surl)
    if errUrl == nil {
        cj = cookiejar.AcquireCookieJar()
        for key, value := range cookieContainer {
            if strings.Contains(key, u.Host) {
                key = strings.Replace(key, u.Host, "", -1)
                valueArry := strings.Split(value, "=")
                value = strings.Split(valueArry[1], ";")[0]
                cj.Set(key, value)
            }
        }
    }
    cj.FillRequest(req)

    req.SetRequestURI(surl)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", getRandomUserAgent())
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    req.Header.Set("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    req.Header.Set("anti-csrftoken-a2z", token)
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.SetMethodBytes(strPost)
    req.SetBodyString(formData)
    err := client.DoTimeout(req, resp, 30*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err, true
    }
    resp.Header.VisitAllCookie(func(key, value []byte) {
        c := fasthttp.AcquireCookie()
        defer fasthttp.ReleaseCookie(c)

        c.ParseBytes(value)
        var emptyContent = string(key) + "=-;"
        if !strings.Contains(string(value), emptyContent) {
            var middle = strings.Replace(string(value), "Domain=.amazon", "domain=.www.amazon", -1)
            middle = strings.Replace(middle, "domain=.amazon", "domain=.www.amazon", -1)
            cookieContainer[string(key)+u.Host] = middle
        }
    })
    contentEncoding := resp.Header.Peek("Content-Encoding")
    var body []byte
    if bytes.EqualFold(contentEncoding, []byte("gzip")) {
        fmt.Println("Unzipping...")
        body, _ = resp.BodyGunzip()
    } else {
        body = resp.Body()
    }
    content := string(body)
    return content, nil, false
}
```

Comment: Firstly, "scrap" and "scrape" are different things.  Regarding your code, why can you not post the relevant snippet here?  Links to offsite resources are not useful.  And in fact, we have no way of knowing if you're trying to deliver malware to unsuspecting people via whatever file you've left at that link.

Comment: I've tried to add a code snippet but it was giving me an error, sorry